# LINQ to SQL where collection contains collection

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I have a problem :(  I have a many-many table between two tables(1&2), via a mapping table(3):

```
(1)Trees / (2)Insects 

TreeID <- (3)TreeInsects -> InsectID
```

And then a one to many relationship:

```
Trees.ID -> Leaves.TreeID
```

And I would like to perform a query which will give me all the Leaves for a collection of insects (via trees-insect mapping table).

E.g. I have `List<Insects>` and I want all Leaves that have an association with any of the Insects in the List via the Tree-Insects mapping table.

This seems like a simple task, but for some reason I'm having trouble doing this!!

The best I have: but the Single() makes it incorrect:

```
   from l in Leaves
            where (from i in Insects
                   select i.ID)
                  .Contains((from ti in l.Tree.TreeInsects
                             select ti.InsectID).Single())
            select l;
```

Comment: It's a Linq-to-Sql generated type based on a Leaves SQL Server table.  The context in my example query would be the Leaves table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm bad with sql-like syntax so I'll write with extensions.

```
ctx.Leaves.Where(l => ctx.TreeInsects.Where( ti => list_with_insects.Select(lwi => lwi.InsectID).Contains( ti.InsectID ) ).Any( ti => ti.TreeID == l.TreeID ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I marked yours as it was the first answer, Grozz's query syntax below works too, I timed them and they perform the same with what data I had in the DB.  Thanks!

Comment: On further analysis, this is the faster query of the two working methods

Answer (score 2):

```
(from i in insectsCollection
select from l in Leaves
       let treeInsectIDs = l.Tree.TreeInsects.Select(ti => ti.InsectID)
       where treeInsectIDs.Contains(i.ID)
       select l)
.SelectMany(l => l)
.Distinct();
```

Comment: The expression within Contains give a no overload compiler expression... any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for this, I marked the earliest correct answer.  I timed this and the answer above and they performed pretty much the same with the data I have. Thanks!

Comment: On further analysis, the other is the faster query of the two working methods

Comment: That may very well be true. Little too much intoxicated to reason about efficiency at the time of writing this :)

Comment: Nice! Worked perfectly for my need to do the same kind of query.

Answer (score 0):

Try investigating the [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) method - I think that may be the key you need.

I would get a list of Trees that are available to that Insect, then peg on a SelectMany to the end and pull out the collection of Leaves tied to that Tree.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> insectIds = localInsects.Select(i => i.ID).ToList();

  //note - each leaf is evaluated, so no duplicates.
IQueryable<Leaf> query =
  from leaf in myDataContext.Leaves
  where leaf.Tree.TreeInsects.Any(ti => insectIds.Contains(ti.InsectId))
  select leaf;


  //note, each matching insect is found, then turned into a collection of leaves.
  // if two insects have the same leaf, that leaf will be duplicated.
IQueryable<Leaf> query2 =
  from insect in myDataContext.Insects
  where insectIds.Contains(insect.ID)
  from ti in insect.TreeInsects
  from leaf in ti.Tree.Leaves
  select leaf;
```

Also note, Sql Server has a parameter limit of ~2100.  LinqToSql will happily generate a query with more insect IDs, but you'll get a sql exception when you try to run it.  To resolve this, run the query more than once, on smaller batches of IDs.

Answer (score 0):

How do you get this list of insects? Is it a query too?

Anyway, if you don't mind performance (SelectMany can be slow if you have a big database), this should work:

```
List<Insect> insects = .... ; //(your query/method)

IEnumerable<Leave> leaves = db.TreeInsects
    .Where(p=> insects.Contains(p.Insect))
    .Select(p=>p.Tree)
    .SelectMany(p=>p.Leaves);
```